# Use nano in the browser (CouchDB javascript interface)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a little bit confused with [nano](https://github.com/dscape/nano).

I would like to use it in the browser only (script(type='text/javascript' src='nano.js')) but it seems that it can be used only in the server (require(nano)).

Anybody can explain to me what should I do to be able to use it on the client and not the server?

Comment: Actually its a node module, you can't use it like a javascript file.

Comment: @Sina Sadrzadeh Do you know any alternative for client side?

Comment: `nano` is very good as a CouchDB client. not like nano, but there are some that written with javascript: [javascript version](http://css.dzone.com/articles/couchdb-javascript) - [jquery version](http://bradley-holt.com/2011/07/couchdb-jquery-plugin-reference/)